# How to access and attach a file in lifecycle hooks (beforeCreate/afterCreate) in Strapi v4 for sending emails with Nodemailer?

Tags: strapi, nodemailer

I'm using Strapi v4 as my backend and I want to send an email using Nodemailer in the beforeCreate or afterCreate lifecycle hook of a content type. I need to access a file uploaded during the creation of the content and attach it to the email. Here's an example of my code:

```
beforeCreate: async (event) => {
  const ctx = strapi.requestContext.get();
  const { full_name, email } = JSON.parse(ctx.request.body.data);
  const file = ctx.request.files;
  const trackingCode = await strapi.config.helperFunction.generateRandomItn(event);
  
  try {
    const emailOptions = {
      to: email,
      subject: subject,
      html: content,
      attachments: [
        {
          filename: file.name,
          path: file.path,
        },
      ],
    };
    
    await strapi.plugins['email'].services.email.send(emailOptions);
    strapi.log.debug(`Email sent`);
  } catch (err) {
    strapi.log.error(`Error sending email`, err);
    throw new ApplicationError(`Error sending email: ${err}`);
  }
},
```

However, I'm unsure how to properly access the file within the lifecycle hook and attach it to the email. I would appreciate any guidance or code examples on how to achieve this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

short answer to your question is `you can’t anymore`

This due to relations are not populated in lifecycles, after someone had 100k relations and bugged strapi goes slow.

Anyway can answer partially:

So you have to use `afterUpdare` or `afterCreate`

To get your data you have to use extra query sadly:

```
const data = await strapi.db.query('api:..').find({ where: { id: event.result.id }, populate { media: true } })
```

Note if you are on ts you likely gonna need ts-ignore (since strapi types are miss aligned)

So next part you gonna need to figure out yourself is part where you actually read file. I guess you can try something like:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra

```
const file = await fs.readFile(`${__dirname}/public/${media.url}`)
```

Good lucks!

Comment: tnx, I tried this one but didn't work because data give me everything except file, show me a file is null

Comment: Yep I think I starting to remember, I had something similar, prolly you have to delay, while file is processed.

Comment: I think I dealt with that with uploading file first and then passing its id to newly created entry

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem and after some research found a solution. Relations (like media) are creating in parallel. So you can't retrieve them in that moment when your entity is creating, but you can get it after while. Its work for me.
Dont forget to populate your media data. In my example its 'file'

```
module.exports = {
    async afterCreate(event) {
        const {result} = event;

        const existingData = await strapi.entityService.findOne("api::job.job", result.id, {populate: ['file']});
        const mediaFileIsNullHere = existingData.file

        setTimeout(async () => {
            const existingData = await strapi.entityService.findOne("api::job.job", result.id, {populate: ['file']});
            const mediaFileIsAvailableHere = existingData.file
            
        // here send email with attached file

        }, 5000)
    }
}
```